# Finding unique solutions of a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm working throug Richard Earl's "Towards Higher Mathematics"
and am stuck on this problem.

> For what real numbers $A, B, C$ does the equation
> $$
> z \bar z + Az + B \bar z = Ci
> $$ have a unique solution $z$?

What exactly does it mean for an equation to have a "unique" solution in this context? Would I be correct in assuming I merely substitute `(a+bi)` and `(a-bi)` and re-write as a quadratic in a or b and then use the discriminant? In that case would `b^2 - 4ac = 0` or `b^2 - 4ac > 0?`

Thanks

Comment: Unique means that a single $z$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: I would interpret unique to mean that there aren't two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ so that $z_1 \neq z_2$ and that they are both the roots of the equation. So yes, the discriminant has to be zero.

Comment: You equation is of second order. That means there may exists 2 solutions but you need to choose A,B and C such that the 2 solutions coincide to only 1 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $z=x+iy$,

$$x^2+y^2+(A+B)x+i(A-B)y-Ci=0.$$

From the imaginary part, $y$ is unique when $$A\ne B.$$

Then

$$x^2+(A+B)x+y^2=0$$ requires $(A+B)^2=4y^2$ or

$$A+B=\pm2y=\pm\frac{2C}{A-B}$$

In other words,

$$A\ne B\land A^2-B^2=\pm2C.$$

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: sorry I'm just going over this again and I don't understand the step A =/= B. Why does that follow?

Comment: @TheAnonymous: write the condition on the imaginary part.

Comment: Do you mean write the discriminant in terms of y? Sorry this is probably trivial but I'm missing one piece of the puzzle here

Comment: @TheAnonymous: in row $7$.